# Create .iso for Windows 8 from "Windows 8 setup" program

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, installation-media

I downloaded Windows 8 through my school, and the only option that we are given is to use the "Windows 8 Setup" program where it downloads and does the install for you. I'm wondering, after the download, is it possible to get an image that can then be used to create a bootable DVD/USB? I'd like to have a backup installation disk, since they only give you 30 days of access to your download. Does anyone know how do to this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just back-up the setup program itself instead?

If it runs straight from the web (highly doubt so), you could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see where it saves it and then copy the temporary folder and put that on an external medium.

Answer (score 1):

If you download from Student Academic Alliance it comes under ISO image. Which you can use for your future installations. You can simply burn it and clean install. Remember the key that we use is probably for a limited time. The contract says 2 yrs.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded from the e-academy Inc. ("onthehub.com") and it comes as a small .exe installer that then does all the downloading. You're allowed to create a disk afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm dumb.

I flew through the installation first because I was excited to see what the new Windows was like. There's an option after you download the files to "Install by creating media."

Don't know how I missed that the first time around...