# Where to find the Windows 8 ISO?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-8, iso-image

I'm on OSX and I've bought Windows 8. I'd like to run it in VirtualBox. I can't seem to find an ISO to download. Do you know where I could find it? (Or is there some other way to set up a vm?)

Comment: "bought Windows 8" in what form?

Comment: As an upgrade. Perhaps I should make a Windows 7 VM first, then upgrade from that haha.

Comment: Related: [Create .iso for Windows 8 from “Windows 8 setup” program?](http://superuser.com/questions/494006/create-iso-for-windows-8-from-windows-8-setup-prgoram?rq=1)

Comment: Why is this question downvoted, while http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft got answered?  They're fundamentally the same, apart from a version difference.

Answer (score 4):

That depends where you bought it from and which version...

1. There is the upgrade version (39.99 for a limited time) that require a previous install and are download only before you can create the restore disc.

   *In this case: You would have to install a different version of windows (XP SP3 or newer, activated with a Valid license) in VBox first, then inside that, download the upgrade pack from the MS Store (Again, assuming you bought it there).*
2. The other notable version is 69.99 and is physical (meaning you wait to get the disc).

   *In this case, you could rip an ISO or install it from physical - if you would like that info, let me know.*

   Here is MS's site for it with that info: [Microsoft Store Online](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbpage.Windows_8_Pro)

   [image: win8buy]

   If you bought it elsewhere, please provide us a link and I will take a look and update my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the Windows 8 Upgrade Advisor/Setup to an existing Windows machine.
- Run it.
- It will download the image and then give you an option to make install media from it.

Comment: Does it require purchase first?

Comment: Yup.  At least once anyway. ;)