# Is there anyway to get direct download link of Windows 8 from technet subscription?

Tags: microsoft-technet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to find the Windows 8 ISO?](https://superuser.com/questions/496374/where-to-find-the-windows-8-iso)

I have a technet subscription and want to get download link of windows 8 for my friend to download it. But I always have to download through akamai downloader which doesn't let me to do that. I wonder if there is anyway to pass it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to find the Windows 8 ISO?](http://superuser.com/questions/496374/where-to-find-the-windows-8-iso) and/or [Where do I download Windows 8 (legally from Microsoft)?](http://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-do-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a username and password to download anything from TechNet, but if you're logged in there should be an option to download via browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only get windows 7 direct download link but not windows 8's.

Comment: @JatSing - Sounds like you don't have an ACTIVE subscription because ALL active Technet subscribers get Windows 8.

Comment: I do, I just wanna get a directlink for my friend to download it.