# Clean install Windows 8 on OEM windows 8 laptop

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, iso-image, oem

Long story short, my Ubuntu partition and my Windows 8 partition had a fight, and they both lost. I have a computer booting nothing at the moment. So I'm trying to figure out how to get a clean-install of Windows 8 on my laptop. The usual refresh/reset features are out. There are no backups. Recovery partitions are gone.

Ideally, I need a Windows 8 (not Pro) ISO to install, but despite my searches, I cannot seem to find one. Anyone have any ideas how I can reset my PC and install Windows 8 again?

Comment: Here is a magnet link you can use to download a clean image from Microsoft.  This iso has both pro and home editions.   

magnet:?xt=urn:btih:482ee377843fb4f7c28dc74a88f556bcd86d1a98&dn=Windows-8-Pro_64‌​-bit

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop came with windows 8, there is an OEM windows 8 key embedded in your BIOS that windows will use to activate.

Simply obtain an install disc for windows 8 (make sure you get the correct version "standard"/Pro) and when installing, [remove all other partitions](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-clean-install-part-1_11.htm) prior to beginning the install.
as far as finding the ISO goes
Review:

[Where can I download Windows 8 legally, from Microsoft?](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft)

[Where can I legally obtain the 64bit version of Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/520826/where-can-i-legally-obtain-the-64bit-version-of-windows-8)

[Where to find the Windows 8 ISO?](https://superuser.com/questions/496374/where-to-find-the-windows-8-iso)

or google `en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso`, but do so at your own risk.