# Where to get Windows 8 ISO

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, iso-image

So I bought my laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed. I had problems and then installed Ubuntu over everything (no recovery left partition left or anything like that).

I'd like to install Windows 8 again but I can't use the Windows 8 installer because I don't have a key **my laptop is the ones that have the key in the bios so installation will recognize it** And I'm not on Windows so I can't run the .exe (even with wine) (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) I'm talking about that.

I need the .iso to burn to a usb so I can install it and windows will grab my key from the bios (hopefully, else I'm screwed).

Or any other way to install Windows 8 without having to pay again.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/571474/clean-install-windows-8-on-oem-windows-8-laptop?rq=1

Comment: Legally, the Official Windows 8 or 8.1 [Installers](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) (the EXEs) are the only way. You can create a Window VM guest for the purpose of downloading and running EXE installers.